# Find text across multiple columns and return value in a different column

Tags: excel

I have 5 columns with email addresses. Each cell of each column contains 1 email address and the domains of the emails on each row don't repeat. I want to find only the emails containing "@gmail.com" and copy the value of that cell to a new column.

Using this can check only 1 column
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",T1)),T1,"")

I need it to check all 5 columns and return the value of the cell containing "@gmail.com"

Comment: Do you mean that the gmail domain is only in one of the five columns? Are you open to a VBA solution?

Comment: @Brian Yes, the gmail domain appears only once per row. I am open to a VBA solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but you'll need to adjust it to your ranges:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim myRow As Range
Dim r As Range

Set myRow = Range("A1:C1")
Do While myRow.Resize(1, 1) <> ""
    For Each r In myRow
        If InStr(1, r, "@gmail.com") Then
            myRow.Offset(0, 3).Resize(1, 1) = r.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next r
    Set myRow = myRow.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'm trying to adjust the output cell, but I will figure it out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want all email addresses contain "@gmail.com) returned:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",T1)),T1,"")& IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",T2)),T2,"") & IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",T3)),T3,"") & 
    IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",T4)),T4,"") &
    IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",T1)),T1,"")
```

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",T1)),T1,"") & IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",U1)),U1,"") & IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",V1)),V1,"") & IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",W1)),W1,"") & IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("@gmail.com",X1)),X1,"")

Comment: This gets the work done, but the thing is there are more than 5 columns and I am looking for a more elegant way to get the value.